# net core 3.1 ajax parameter is not being sent to the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to issue an ajax call from my razor file to my net core 3.1 controller
I placed a break point at the beginning of the controller method
I noticed that the call made it to the controller method however that parameter is always null

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("Freeze", "Admin")',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
type: 'POST',
cache: false,
data: JSON.stringify(data) ,
success: function (data) {
alert('Freeze successful');
$('#tombstoneView').html(data);
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
alert('Error');
alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Freeze([FromBody]FreezeModel model)
```

## FreezeModel

```
public class FreezeModel
{
public int productId { get; set; }
public string[] refPeriods { get; set; } = null;
public string freezeReason { get; set; }
public string freezeAuthorizer { get; set; }
}
```

I used the browser debugger and I see my values in the request payload
[image]

I tried to output JSON.stringify(data) and got this
{"productId":"10100039","freezeReason":"ttt","freezeAuthorizer":"","refPeriods":null}

Comment: Just try `data: data` instead of `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @PriyankPanchal just tried it and the model is null when it hits the controller

Comment: I could pass the parameter successfully by using your code.Could you share your entire razor view and your Startup.cs?Did you custom any model binder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use controller method like (i.e. remove [FromBody])

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Freeze(FreezeModel model)
```

ajax call to submit form

```
$('#testform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#testform').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Freeze", "Test")',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Freeze successful');
                $('#tombstoneView').html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error');
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

[image]

Comment: i already tried this but it didnt work. all of my ajax calls are not working!!

Comment: @Mikey I modified answer please try that one. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the code snippet. My values are hidden inputs in the page and I see your submitting the whole form, how can I modify your snippet to use the hidden element value

Comment: You can use code like  var data = { productId: $('#productId').val(), freezeReason: $('#freezeReason').val(), freezeAuthorizer: $('#freezeAuthorizer').val()  };
            $.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("Freeze", "Test")',  type: 'POST',cache: false, data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Freeze successful');
                    $('#tombstoneView').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error');
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218925/discussion-between-mikey-and-rutuja).